# Create nested div from json result

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, html

I recieve from an AJAX call `data` which has an architecture like

```
data
[0] =>
      "date" => "blah"
      "location" => "blah"
      ...
[1] =>
      "date" => "moreblah"...................
```

I would like to create nested divs for each of the elements in data like this

    
        blah
        blah
        ...
    
    
        moreblah
        ...
    .....

I have:

```
for(var i in data){
    $("<div class='event_item'>").appendTo("#thelist");
    //make div class "date" with event.date inside
    $("<div class='date'>" + data[i].date + "</div>").appendTo("#thelist");
    //make div class "location" with event.location inside
    $("<div class='location'>" + data[i].location + "</div>").appendTo("#thelist");
    //make div class "descrip" with event.descrip inside
    $("<div class='descrip'>" + data[i].description + "</div>").appendTo("#thelist");
    //make div class "detail" with event.extra inside
    $("<div class='detail'>" + data[i].extra + "</div>").appendTo("#thelist");
    $("</div>").appendTo("#thelist");
}
```

this doesn't work.. what i really want to do is append it to the newly created "event" div... not the list... how can i do that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: hardly sokmeoen will understand what your problem. Post your html and post the html you would want

Comment: Is the code you get back from AJAX call supposed to be json data? Sure doesn't look like it.

Comment: have you seen/considered jQuery templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this: also, make sure use always create complete html tags. You're adding dom elements, not printing something to the document, Thus: do's: `$('<div></div>);`.  Dont's: `$('</div>')`.

```
for(var i in data){

    var event = $("<div class='event_item'></div>");
    //make div class "date" with event.date inside
    $("<div class='date'>" + data[i].date + "</div>").appendTo(event);
    //make div class "location" with event.location inside
    $("<div class='location'>" + data[i].location + "</div>").appendTo(event);
    //make div class "descrip" with event.descrip inside
    $("<div class='descrip'>" + data[i].description + "</div>").appendTo(event);
    //make div class "detail" with event.extra inside
    $("<div class='detail'>" + data[i].extra + "</div>").appendTo(event);
    console.log(event);
    $(event).appendTo('#theList');
}
```

To play around with it, see the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fn3Fm/

Comment: Thanks, I'm not quite used to using variables for dom elements

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the new div.
2. Append it to the list.

   ```
   for(var i in data){
       var event = $("<div class='event_item'></div>");
       event.append("<div class='date'>" + data[i].date + "</div>");
       // ... other stuff for the event div

       $("#thelist").append(event);
   }
   ```

Comment: I would be very concerned about naming a local variable "event". If it's not a reserved word (and javascript has many)-- then it should be. I also think this code above is incorrect. This line looks bad for a number of reasons - event.append('</div>); No closing quote plus you don't need append a closing div element anyway.

Comment: @ek_ny: already fixed that :-) and event isn't a reserved word in js.